# Eliminating duplicates error in Visual Studio Development Tool for Tabular and SQL services

Tags: dax, powerquery, m, ssas-tabular

I have a question about my M code.  I am currently working in Visual Studio and 'Editing Expressions' via VSDT.  The problem that I have is that I am trying to create a relationship between one dimension table and another fact table using a primary key.  The primary key in the Dim table has unique values, or so it seems.  I have removed nulls and blanks in the primary key column.  I started off creating the PK by concatenating three columns shared between the two tables.  Further, I have removed duplicates and run this command in the PQ editor.  I am puzzled as to why, when I join the two tables, I get an error message saying that my Dim table does not have unique values.  More frustrating is when I sort the data ascending and descending and I find no blanks, where there once was a blank.  I am puzzled about how to fix this problem.  I've tried 16 different ways to Sunday-- even moving some of the query steps around.  To no avail...

The error thrown:

> **Error:  Failed to save modifications to the server.  Column Style_List_PK in Table dStyles contains blank values and this is not
>   allowed for columns on the one-side of a one-to-many relationship or
>   for columns that are used as a primary key of a table.**

The code:

```
let
    Source = #"SQL/sbsqld59;PJ",
    dbo_Style_List = Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="Style_List"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(dbo_Style_List,{{"Brand", type text}, {"Style", type text}, {"Style Description", type text}, {"Sizes", type any}, {"Style Name", type text}, {"General Category", type text}, {"Style Category", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Sizes", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Sizes.1", "Sizes.2", "Sizes.3", "Sizes.4", "Sizes.5", "Sizes.6", "Sizes.7", "Sizes.8", "Sizes.9"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Sizes.1", type text}, {"Sizes.2", type text}, {"Sizes.3", type text}, {"Sizes.4", type text}, {"Sizes.5", type text}, {"Sizes.6", type text}, {"Sizes.7", type text}, {"Sizes.8", type text}, {"Sizes.9", type text}}),
    #"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Changed Type1", {{"Sizes.1", "NULL"}, {"Sizes.2", "NULL"}, {"Sizes.3", "NULL"}, {"Sizes.4", "NULL"}, {"Sizes.5", "NULL"}, {"Sizes.6", "NULL"}, {"Sizes.7", "NULL"}, {"Sizes.8", "NULL"}, {"Sizes.9", "NULL"}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Replaced Errors", {"Brand", "Style", "Style Description", "Style Name", "General Category", "Style Category"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Value", "Size"}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Renamed Columns","","NULL",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Brand", "Style", "Style Description", "Style Name", "General Category", "Style Category", "Size"}),
    #"Uppercased Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Replaced Value",{{"Style", Text.Upper, type text}, {"Brand", Text.Upper, type text}, {"Size", Text.Upper, type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Uppercased Text", "Style_List_PK", each Text.Combine({[Brand],[Style],[Size]})),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"Style_List_PK", type text}}),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type2",{{"Style_List_PK", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Trimmed Text", {"Style_List_PK"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Duplicates", each [Style_List_PK] <> null and [Style_List_PK] <> "" and [Style_List_PK] <> " " and [Style_List_PK] <> "  ")
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Comment: **Update: 1/31/2020.  There really is no problem with the code, above.  It eliminates blanks in the Style_List_PK column and allows a 1:M tie to a fact table in the model now.  My issue was in not changing the PARTITION query code for the dStyle table.  Once I did this, the relationship builder allowed a reltnshp to be created.  However, now the problem is with the metadata.  I either need to clear the metadata or find out how to fix meta so that it too, understands that there is a 1:M relationship.

Comment: VS allows the relationship to be built now.  However, when I go to deploy the solution, VS says that the metadata still thinks that an invalid 1:M is being created.